# how to save value on table grails?

Tags: forms, grails, parameters

my image..
http://www.4shared.com/photo/Rj_0Ymdt/1111.html
this is my coding in controller

```
def simpan(){
def banklimit = new BankLimit()
    for(int i = 0; i<params.limitPerDay.size();i++) {
        def baaa = CurrencyList.list(params)
        banklimit.dayLimit = params.limitPerDay[i].toBigDecimal()
        banklimit.alertLimit = (banklimit.dayLimit*0.8)     
        banklimit.currency = CurrencyList.findBySym(baaa.sym[i])
        banklimit.save()
    }
    return banklimit
}

<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>                        
                        <g:sortableColumn property="sym" title="${message(code: 'banklimit.currency.sym.label', default: 'Simbol')}" />                     
                        <g:sortableColumn property="limitday" title="${message(code: 'banklimit.dayLimit.label', default: 'Limit/Day')}" />                     
                </tr>           
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${aaa}" status="i" var="bbb">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                    <td id="${bbb.id}"> ${fieldValue(bean: bbb, field: "sym")}</td>
                    <td  id="${bbb.id}" colspan="2"> <g:textField name="limitPerDay" value="${value}" /></td>               
                </tr>

            </g:each>   
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><g:submitButton name="save" value="SAVE" /> <g:actionSubmit action="back" value="BACK" /></td>
                </tr>           
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

i want to save the field on coloum limit /day if i click "SAVE" buttons.
based my coding, when i click save, only the last row was save in database...
example : theres 4 row..
row 1,2,3,4 filled, then i click save..why only 4th rows save in database? row 1 ,2,3 arenot saving?

Comment: Few things "wrong" here, but I'll go with changing g:textField name="limitPerDay" to g:textField name="limitPerDay[${i}]".  Besides that, you shouldn't have two td tags with the same id, and I'm assuming there's a <form> tag somewhere?  Finally, this code will only ever create NEW rows, not edit rows that already exist, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just one `banklimit = new BankLimit()` but saving it 4 times. it's *one object* saved 4 times with different values in loop.

You need:

```
for(int i = 0; i<params.limitPerDay.size();i++) {
    def banklimit = new BankLimit()
    //.... fill with values
    banklimit.save()
}
```

For client side it's better to make:

```
<g:each in="${aaa}" status="i" var="bbb">
    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
        <td>${fieldValue(bean: bbb, field: "sym")}</td>
        <td colspan="2"><g:textField name="limitPerDay[${i}]" value="${value}" /></td>               
    </tr>
</g:each>
```

Comment: @bill James : how can i take the limitPerDay size for looping?

Comment: oh, i though you already have `limitPerDay` list. Take a look at my answer update then

Comment: i already change like that,but the params.limitPerday.size() can't be detect..its the error's message : Cannot invoke method size() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot invoke method size() on null object

Comment: <g:textField name="limitPerDay[${i}]" value="${value}" /> this limitPerDay's size can't be take the value into controller..?

Comment: if the table have 5 rows,then the itterate(looping) until 5..so the 5 rows can be save ...

Comment: use `params.limitPerDay`, not `params.limitPerday`